# How to get the current test configuration in ginkgo

Tags: go, automated-tests, ginkgo

Say I am runing a test suites, is there a way to get the information of the current test that's running, for example, its labels or its text?

my use case is as follows: I have a test suite which contains several tests and implements an AfterEach, so all tests when done, the code in AfterEach block is executed.

there are few tests out of these, that I want to treat differently in AfterEach. I identify these tests by their texts.

What I have found so far:
GinkgoLabelFilter() ([ref](https://github.com/onsi/ginkgo/issues/111)): gets the labels list that is passed when running the suite
and GinkgoSConfiguration()

BTW this can be done by using a parameter to initialize it on these tests, check it in AfterEach, and act accordingly, but I am interested to know if there is a nicer ginkgo way to do this.

your ideas are appreciated